# Extract Clash of Clans images from Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, archive

I want to extract Clash of Clans game's images and animations from its android apk file. This is for a personal project and I want to add all characters and buildings in the projects.

I extracted the apk file and found the music but I didn't find any images/drawable assets which resemble any character/building.

There are some files with extension '.sc' and I doubt that they could be the files which I need. But I am not sure what are these and how to get the gif/png out of them? I found those file inside the game's apk at \assets\sc\ path.

Can anyone help me here, please?

Comment: I'd also like to know if you find out... the most I can find is either the .sc files are a type of encrypted archive, or the resources.arsc might have the files we need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any luck with this? I've also been looking for a way to decompress and came across this repo that decompresses some files, but I can't find a way to decompress the images/icons
https://github.com/amaanq/apk-updater

Answer (score 0):

1. To extract png from encrypted `.sc` files you can install and use **X-coder** provided in the following link https://github.com/lilmuff2/X-coder?tab=readme-ov-file
2. In addition there are some `.ktx` files located else where in the extracted apk files that you can export as .png files also. you can use **PVRTexTool** corresponding to your OS in the following the link https://developer.imaginationtech.com/downloads/

Tested on some version of Clash of Clans from 2024.